# Returing all records including duplicated with MySQL IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming both `fk` equal to 1 and 3 exists in the table, the following query will return two records.

```
SELECT fk, name FROM my_table WHERE fk IN (1,3,1);
```

How can I instead return three records:

```
fk name
1  john
3  mary
1  john
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `join` instead:

```
select t.fk, t.name
from my_table t join
     (select 1 as x union all select 3 union all select 1
     ) vals
     on t.fk = vals.x;
```

If you also want to keep the ordering, then use a second column -- the order of the rows after the `join` is not guaranteed unless you include an `order by`:

```
select t.fk, t.name
from my_table t join
     (select 1 as x, 1 as ordering union all
      select 3, 2 union all
      select 1, 3
     ) vals
     on t.fk = vals.x
order by vals.ordering;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  Yikes!  What if instead of `1, 3, 1`, I had one hundred values?  Seems like I should probably use a simple `IN` clause and the application.

Comment: @user1032531 . . . Then you would have a derived table or temporary table with all the values.